# Find the area and the circumference of a rectangle and circle attached

Tags: geometry

[image]

Find it's circumference and the area

As you see in the picture, it's width is not given but here is what I have tried but can't continue because I have no idea how to find the width of the rectangle.

I started with the circle and found the perimeter and circumference

perimeter: pi*r^2

P: pi*31.5^2 = 3117.24m^2
C: pi*2*31.5= 197.92m

And I do not know how to continue with the rectangle. Or am I even doing this right?

Comment: The width of the rectangle is the same as the diameter of the circle.

Comment: Oh lol, I meant the area haha.. Wow what a smart guy I am.

Comment: The diagram seems to suggest the rectangle is $101$m wide and two radii high, but only the $101$m affects the perimeter (twice)

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a figure that consists of a rectangle and two semicircles of the same radii. Let $r=31.5$ be the radius of the semicircle and $\ell = 101$ the side of the rectangle.

The perimeter for the figure you have given will be equivalent to adding the sides of the rectangle and half the circumference for both of the semicircles. Since the semicircles have the same radii, you can simply add the two sides of the rectangle and the circumference of the circle with radius $r$.

Thus, the perimeter of your figure is given by
$$
2\ell + 2\pi r = 2(101)+2\pi(31.5) \approx 399.92.
$$

**For the area:** The area will simply be the area of the circle with radius $r$ plus the area of the given rectangle with sides $\ell$ and $2r$. Thus, the area is given by
$$
\pi r^2 + \ell\cdot r = \pi(31.5^2)+101\cdot (2\cdot 31.5) \approx 9480.25.
$$

Comment: Invalid area, it is 9480.24m^2.. l*w + pi*r^2 = 101*63 + pi*31.5^2 = 9480.24m^2.

Comment: Oh ok, please do. And check my calculation of the area if it is correct the way I did.

Comment: Oh by the way how exactly do you know if the width is 63.. The radius of the semi circle is 31.5 but is there a specific formula? Or do you just guess.

Comment: @MathDCLass Your perimeter calculation only concerns the circle, and it looks fine (you calculated the perimeter of the semicircles added together). To get the perimeter for the entire figure, then, you must add the lengths of the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: @MathDCLass No, you do not guess--the semicircle is affixed to the rectangle. Since $r$ is the *radius* of the circle, you know the *diameter* is $2r$, and the diameter is what covers the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: Wow that was very informative. I thank you a lot! Oh and before I keep asking more questions on here, do you have the time to tutor me few geometry questions? I am staying up all night studying for my test today. About 00:02am where I live in.

Comment: @MathDCLass Simply post whatever questions you have on MSE and usually you will get a response (just like you did with this question). The idea is for the *community* to help individuals, not for individuals to tutor other users.

Comment: Alright, I very much thank you although.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add up the length of the parts!

The length of the rectangle sides are 101 each, and there are two. The circumference of the two half circles is that of a full circle (obviously), with radius 31.5, so the total circumference is:

$2(101)+\pi (31.5)2 \approx 400$